# Convert a List to a given Type

Tags: c#, list, types, casting, type-conversion

I have the following List:

```
public List<EntityBase> PossibleReplacements
```

I also have a Type

```
public Type type;
```

type will contain a certain class type that inherits EntityBase (That's how my app works). 
Now I need to cast the list PossibleReplacements to a List of type 'type'

Something like this:

```
List<type> lijst = PossibleReplacements.Cast<type>();
```

but this gives an error

```
'ReplacePopupModel.type' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'
```

I have yet to find a working solution for this.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Try typeof(type) when you call Cast<>.

Comment: You cannot do this in a type-safe manner, your type is not known at compile time

Comment: Seems more like a lack of understanding of generics in general. what are you trying to do with the List<type> ?

Comment: I changed my app logic a little bit, and managed to fixed my problem using Generics. Thanks alot to everyone for the good advice on type-safety.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `Cast` since it is not in type-safe at runtime, you just use `where` to select:

```
var lijst = PossibleReplacements.Where(t => t.GetType() == type);
```

Comment: He does not want to get the types, the OP wants to cast to a given type instance.

Comment: Convert.ChangeType will fail at runtime...  Also, this will not compile as Select will return `IEnumerable<Object>` from this query.

Comment: It's still won't compile, you can't have there `List<Type>`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the items out that match the type like so:

```
List<EntityBase> list = PossibleReplacements.Where(e => type.IsAssignableFrom(e.GetType())).ToList();
```

This list will only contain items that match (or are subclasses of) the specific type you specified in `type`.

However, you can't cast to the specific `List<T>` type because this isn't known at compile time.

If you are trying to extract items of a specific type *known at compile time*, you can just use:

```
List<TheType> list = PossibleReplacements.OfType<TheType>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not without reflection, and not safe. But you can follow Reed Copseys first hint and check if all entries are assignable to your type and then use the reflected cast method:

```
var type = ...your type...

var cast = typeof(IEnumerable<>).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(type);
var list = cast.Invoke(PossibleReplacements, null);
```

The variable `list` is now `object`, but has an reference to a list of the right type. As you don't know your actual type, you may have some interface to access the list (cast required).